# bxslider scaling in mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bxslider

Using css

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 585px) {}
```

to arrange a mobile layout. BX Slider is resizing, but in mobile mode, the slider breaks the width somehow (though, not visually) and scales the viewport.

Not sure how I could restrict this issue either. My ideal viewport width is 585px, but that doesn't seem to fix it.

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=584px">
```

Comment: This issue is still unresolved. check out stack overflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13722282/bxslider-calculating-wrong-viewport-size-on-load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to achieve can be done with meta tags.

Prevent scaling:

```
<meta name="viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale = 2.3, user-scalable = no" />
```

Comment: Sometimes it is hard to find the right size, but this meta tag should do the trick for ios scaling. Good Luck!